# Is the Golang multiple return overloading unique to the map type?

Tags: syntax, go, overloading

These both work:

```
m := make(map[int]int)
elem, ok := m[1]
elem = m[1]
```

Yet, this not allowed:

```
func overload() (int, int) {
    return 1, 1
}

func overload() int {
    return 1
}

func main() {
    x := overload()
    x, y := overload()
}
```

Also, is there a list of built-in syntax that doesn't generalize? I keep getting confused on what is a special syntax, i.e. `map[string]int`, `make([]int, 10)` and what is part of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go doesn't support overloading even if the two functions have different arity in parameters or return values or even if the parameters have different parameter or return types.

http://golang.org/doc/faq#overloading

There is no list of special identifiers or special rules that the built-ins get away with as far as I know. However, they seem to be few and far in-between.

Comment: So the `map` and `for i := range blah { }`, `for i, x := range blah { }` are all special?

Comment: Yes, those are special syntax. 

For user-defined functions, the idiom is to create wrapper functions for different arguments/return values.

e.g. `k := customMap.GetKey()`, `k, v := customMap.GetKeyValue()`

Answer (score 7):

It's special syntax. Besides the map key check, at least [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) and [channel receive](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) have one- and two-element versions. In all those cases, the second element is a `bool` called `ok` in the doc examples; for type assertions it says whether the assertion succeeded and for channel receives it says whether the communication succeeded (`false` if the channel is closed and empty).

`for...range` has its own, different one- and two-element versions, though maybe `range` is more-obviously special.

There is a [list of built-in functions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Built-in_functions). If you really want to know all of the corner cases, [go over the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec)--it is pretty short, not bogged down in the sorts of details some standards documents are, and worth the time once you've played with the language a bit. ([Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) and [the FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/faq) are also in this category.)

Answer (score 0):

The example you are given are not method overloading.

1st Example: Show whether key exist in map or not.

```
m := make(map[int]int)
elem, ok := m[1]
elem = m[1]
```

`elem` will receive either the value of "1" from the map or a "zero value" and ok will receive a bool that will be set to true if "foo" was actually present in the map.

Officially Site: [Go not support overloading of methods and operators?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#overloading)

> Method dispatch is simplified if it doesn't need to do type matching
>   as well. Experience with other languages told us that having a variety
>   of methods with the same name but different signatures was
>   occasionally useful but that it could also be confusing and fragile in
>   practice. Matching only by name and requiring consistency in the types
>   was a major simplifying decision in Go's type system.

Golang supports variadic functions and methods. That is a another way you can (more or less) do function and method overloading in Golang.

> A variadic function or method is a function or method that accepts a
>   variable number of parameters.

[Example](http://play.golang.org/p/edhQHrQ54z):

```
o1 := Overload(1, 2, 3)
o2 := Overload(153, 196883, 1729, 1634, 5, 36)
o3 := Overload(1, -2)
```

For more details you can look to this post: [Function and Method Overloading in Golang.](http://changelog.ca/log/2015/01/30/golang)